# Arduino ESP8266 HTTPS server How to install SSL certificate

Tags: android, ssl, https, certificate, esp8266

I made HTTP server on my NodeMCU ESP8266 board using ESP8266WebServer library. I would like to convert it to the HTTPS server, so I used ESP8266WebServerSecure library, bought SSL certificate and got 3 files:

```
certificate.cert
dv_ca.pem
private.pem
```

Could someone explain me how should I install it on my server? Below my code when I was trying to launch https server with self-generated certificate, but there was a problem to connect it using android application(Trust anchor not found for Android SSL connection).

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServerSecure.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define output4 4
#define output5 5
#define input0 A0


const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "password";

 //HTTPS server object, port number 443
BearSSL::ESP8266WebServerSecure server(443);

static const char serverCert[] PROGMEM = R"EOF(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

)EOF";

static const char serverKey[] PROGMEM =  R"EOF(
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

)EOF";

void handleNotFound() { 
   String message = "No such a data or incorrect request...";
   server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}

void changeStatus(){
    //Parsing request argument to string
  String postBody = server.arg("plain");
    //Changing output value condition
  if(server.hasArg("number")&&server.hasArg("status")){
    int pinNumber = server.arg("number").toInt();
    if(server.arg("status")=="on"){
      digitalWrite(pinNumber, HIGH);
    } else if(server.arg("status")=="off"){
      digitalWrite(pinNumber, LOW);
    } 
  } else {
      handleNotFound();
    }
  Serial.println("Argument: "+postBody);
  server.send(200, "text/plain", postBody); 
}
 
void getStatus(){
    //Creating json document
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(200);
    //Pushing data to json document
  if(digitalRead(output4)==LOW){
    JsonObject out4 = doc.createNestedObject("sensor 4");
    out4["name"] = "output4";
    out4["value"] = 0;
  } else {
    JsonObject out4 = doc.createNestedObject("sensor 4");
    out4["name"] = "output4";
    out4["value"] = 1;
  }
  if(digitalRead(output5)==LOW){
    JsonObject out5 = doc.createNestedObject("sensor 5");
    out5["name"] = "output5";
    out5["value"] = 0;
  } else {
    JsonObject out5 = doc.createNestedObject("sensor 5");
    out5["name"] = "output5";
    out5["value"] = 1;
  }
    //Getting analog input value
    JsonObject in0 = doc.createNestedObject("sensor 0");
    in0["name"] = "input0";
    in0["value"] = analogRead(A0);
    //Variable co
   String outputData = "";
   serializeJsonPretty(doc, outputData);
   server.send(200, "application/json", outputData);
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Initialize the output variables as outputs
  pinMode(output5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(output4, OUTPUT);
  // Set outputs to LOW
  digitalWrite(output5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(output4, LOW);

  //Get current time
  configTime(3 * 3600, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
  //Start wifi connection
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Trying to connect wifi network");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  Serial.print("IP adress: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 //Handling requests
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, getStatus);
  server.on("/led", HTTP_GET, changeStatus);
  //Setting server certificate and key
  server.getServer().setRSACert(new BearSSL::X509List(serverCert), new BearSSL::PrivateKey(serverKey));
  // Start server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Secured server ready");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  // Handling incoming client requests in loop
   server.handleClient();
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is from examples of ESP8266. Change the certificate except testing purposes. You can get a certificate from internet or generate it with `make-self-signed-cert.sh` which is located in `ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiHTTPSServer`. Before execution of `make-self-signed-cert.sh`, modify the script.Find `your-name-here` and replace it with your name or organization name. Then execute the script. At the end of the execution, there will be new files that named as `key.h` and `x509.h`. Certificate codes are in the two new files. Copy&paste them into the arduino code.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "your-ssid"
#define STAPSK  "your-password"
#endif

const char* ssid = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

// The certificate is stored in PMEM
static const uint8_t x509[] PROGMEM = {
  0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x3d, 0x30, 0x81, 0xe8, 0x02, 0x09, 0x00, 0xfe, 0x56,
  0x46, 0xf2, 0x78, 0xc6, 0x51, 0x17, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86,
  0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x0b, 0x05, 0x00, 0x30, 0x26, 0x31,
  0x10, 0x30, 0x0e, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55, 0x04, 0x0a, 0x0c, 0x07, 0x45, 0x53,
  0x50, 0x38, 0x32, 0x36, 0x36, 0x31, 0x12, 0x30, 0x10, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55,
  0x04, 0x03, 0x0c, 0x09, 0x31, 0x32, 0x37, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2e,
  0x31, 0x30, 0x1e, 0x17, 0x0d, 0x31, 0x37, 0x30, 0x33, 0x31, 0x38, 0x31,
  0x34, 0x34, 0x39, 0x31, 0x38, 0x5a, 0x17, 0x0d, 0x33, 0x30, 0x31, 0x31,
  0x32, 0x35, 0x31, 0x34, 0x34, 0x39, 0x31, 0x38, 0x5a, 0x30, 0x26, 0x31,
  0x10, 0x30, 0x0e, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55, 0x04, 0x0a, 0x0c, 0x07, 0x45, 0x53,
  0x50, 0x38, 0x32, 0x36, 0x36, 0x31, 0x12, 0x30, 0x10, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55,
  0x04, 0x03, 0x0c, 0x09, 0x31, 0x32, 0x37, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2e,
  0x31, 0x30, 0x5c, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7,
  0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x4b, 0x00, 0x30, 0x48, 0x02,
  0x41, 0x00, 0xc6, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x12, 0xe1, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x10, 0x0c, 0xf7,
  0x3a, 0x2a, 0x5a, 0x49, 0xe2, 0x2d, 0xc9, 0x7a, 0x63, 0x1d, 0xef, 0xc6,
  0xbb, 0xa3, 0xd6, 0x6f, 0x59, 0xcb, 0xd5, 0xf6, 0xbe, 0x34, 0x83, 0x33,
  0x50, 0x80, 0xec, 0x49, 0x63, 0xbf, 0xee, 0x59, 0x94, 0x67, 0x8b, 0x8d,
  0x81, 0x85, 0x23, 0x24, 0x06, 0x52, 0x76, 0x55, 0x9d, 0x18, 0x09, 0xb3,
  0x3c, 0x10, 0x40, 0x05, 0x01, 0xf3, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x30,
  0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x0b,
  0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x41, 0x00, 0x69, 0xdc, 0x6c, 0x9b, 0xa7, 0x62, 0x57,
  0x7e, 0x03, 0x01, 0x45, 0xad, 0x9a, 0x83, 0x90, 0x3a, 0xe7, 0xdf, 0xe8,
  0x8f, 0x46, 0x00, 0xd3, 0x5f, 0x2b, 0x0a, 0xde, 0x92, 0x1b, 0xc5, 0x04,
  0xc5, 0xc0, 0x76, 0xf4, 0xf6, 0x08, 0x36, 0x97, 0x27, 0x82, 0xf1, 0x60,
  0x76, 0xc2, 0xcd, 0x67, 0x6c, 0x4b, 0x6c, 0xca, 0xfd, 0x97, 0xfd, 0x33,
  0x9e, 0x12, 0x67, 0x6b, 0x98, 0x7e, 0xd5, 0x80, 0x8f
};

// And so is the key.  These could also be in DRAM
static const uint8_t rsakey[] PROGMEM = {
  0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x3a, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x41, 0x00, 0xc6, 0x72,
  0x6c, 0x12, 0xe1, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x10, 0x0c, 0xf7, 0x3a, 0x2a, 0x5a, 0x49,
  0xe2, 0x2d, 0xc9, 0x7a, 0x63, 0x1d, 0xef, 0xc6, 0xbb, 0xa3, 0xd6, 0x6f,
  0x59, 0xcb, 0xd5, 0xf6, 0xbe, 0x34, 0x83, 0x33, 0x50, 0x80, 0xec, 0x49,
  0x63, 0xbf, 0xee, 0x59, 0x94, 0x67, 0x8b, 0x8d, 0x81, 0x85, 0x23, 0x24,
  0x06, 0x52, 0x76, 0x55, 0x9d, 0x18, 0x09, 0xb3, 0x3c, 0x10, 0x40, 0x05,
  0x01, 0xf3, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x40, 0x35, 0x0b, 0x74,
  0xd3, 0xff, 0x15, 0x51, 0x44, 0x0f, 0x13, 0x2e, 0x9b, 0x0f, 0x93, 0x5c,
  0x3f, 0xfc, 0xf1, 0x17, 0xf9, 0x72, 0x94, 0x5e, 0xa7, 0xc6, 0xb3, 0xf0,
  0xfe, 0xc9, 0x6c, 0xb1, 0x1e, 0x83, 0xb3, 0xc6, 0x45, 0x3a, 0x25, 0x60,
  0x7c, 0x3d, 0x92, 0x7d, 0x53, 0xec, 0x49, 0x8d, 0xb5, 0x45, 0x10, 0x99,
  0x9b, 0xc6, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x68, 0xc7, 0x13, 0x4e, 0xb6, 0x04, 0x61, 0x21,
  0x01, 0x02, 0x21, 0x00, 0xea, 0x8c, 0x21, 0xd4, 0x7f, 0x3f, 0xb6, 0x91,
  0xfa, 0xf8, 0xb9, 0x2d, 0xcb, 0x36, 0x36, 0x02, 0x5f, 0xf0, 0x0c, 0x6e,
  0x87, 0xaa, 0x5c, 0x14, 0xf6, 0x56, 0x8e, 0x12, 0x92, 0x25, 0xde, 0xb3,
  0x02, 0x21, 0x00, 0xd8, 0x99, 0x01, 0xf1, 0x04, 0x0b, 0x98, 0xa3, 0x71,
  0x56, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x6f, 0x45, 0xd1, 0x36, 0x70, 0x76, 0x8b, 0xab, 0x69,
  0x30, 0x58, 0x9c, 0xe0, 0x45, 0x97, 0xe7, 0xb6, 0xb5, 0xef, 0xc1, 0x02,
  0x21, 0x00, 0xa2, 0x01, 0x06, 0xc0, 0xf2, 0xdf, 0xbc, 0x28, 0x1a, 0xb4,
  0xbf, 0x9b, 0x5c, 0xd8, 0x65, 0xf7, 0xbf, 0xf2, 0x5b, 0x73, 0xe0, 0xeb,
  0x0f, 0xcd, 0x3e, 0xd5, 0x4c, 0x2e, 0x91, 0x99, 0xec, 0xb7, 0x02, 0x20,
  0x4b, 0x9d, 0x46, 0xd7, 0x3c, 0x01, 0x4c, 0x5d, 0x2a, 0xb0, 0xd4, 0xaa,
  0xc6, 0x03, 0xca, 0xa0, 0xc5, 0xac, 0x2c, 0xe0, 0x3f, 0x4d, 0x98, 0x71,
  0xd3, 0xbd, 0x97, 0xe5, 0x55, 0x9c, 0xb8, 0x41, 0x02, 0x20, 0x02, 0x42,
  0x9f, 0xd1, 0x06, 0x35, 0x3b, 0x42, 0xf5, 0x64, 0xaf, 0x6d, 0xbf, 0xcd,
  0x2c, 0x3a, 0xcd, 0x0a, 0x9a, 0x4d, 0x7c, 0xad, 0x29, 0xd6, 0x36, 0x57,
  0xd5, 0xdf, 0x34, 0xeb, 0x26, 0x03
};

// Create an instance of the server
// specify the port to listen on as an argument
WiFiServerSecure server(443);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // prepare GPIO2
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, 0);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Set the certificates from PMEM (if using DRAM remove the _P from the call)
  server.setServerKeyAndCert_P(rsakey, sizeof(rsakey), x509, sizeof(x509));

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClientSecure client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  unsigned long timeout = millis() + 3000;
  while (!client.available() && millis() < timeout) {
    delay(1);
  }
  if (millis() > timeout) {
    Serial.println("timeout");
    client.flush();
    client.stop();
    return;
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String req = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(req);
  client.flush();

  // Match the request
  int val;
  if (req.indexOf("/gpio/0") != -1) {
    val = 0;
  } else if (req.indexOf("/gpio/1") != -1) {
    val = 1;
  } else {
    Serial.println("invalid request");
    client.print("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html><body>Not found</body></html>");
    return;
  }

  // Set GPIO2 according to the request
  digitalWrite(2, val);

  client.flush();

  // Prepare the response
  String s = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>\r\nGPIO is now ";
  s += (val) ? "high" : "low";
  s += "</html>\n";

  // Send the response to the client
  client.print(s);
  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disconnected");

  // The client will actually be disconnected
  // when the function returns and 'client' object is detroyed
}
```